# Javascript Effective way to do Event Scheduling,

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to write a bot in discord user can set up reminders, however, I am not sure what are the most effective way to do it.

My initial thought was based on

**Method 1 - set interval**

```js
var events = [ 
   //difference datetime
]
setInterval(() => check(), 60000); //Everyminutes)

function check(){
   events.forEach(event =>{
      if (Date.now() >= event.time){/*do somthing */}
   })
}
```

However, I am not sure whether this is the best way to do it, so I decided totry using `setTimeout`, something like this.

**Method 2 - set timeout**

```js
var events = [ 
   //difference datetime
]

bot.on('ready', ()=>{
   events.forEach(event=>{
      setTimeout( /*do somthing */, event.time)
   })
}
```

Just wondering, is method 1 better? Are setInterval and setTimeout the best way to do it or are there any other ways or api/library that make it more effective? (Or are the difference too small)

Comment: `if (Date.now() == event.time){/*do somthing */}`this will not work most of the time, since you simple miss the very exact millisecond of event.time. Better use `>=` instead.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller Thanks for the note, I did that on my actual code, forgot to use >= here.

Comment: `setTimeout` has the disadvantage that when your code crashes, the reminder is lost. `setInterval` has the disadvantage that if your checking logic is complicated you are wasting cycles but this is the approach I would personally go for. Keep the logic simple and check every second. (As in don't open a database connection every second to execute a SQL query...)

Comment: @TinNguyen The problem with the lost reminders in case of a crash is not really there. On startup, you have to setup those Timeouts anyway, no matter if the startup happens after a crash or after a regular shutdown for whatever reason. But by doing it with setInterval and check the list every second, you have a new problem: Once the event processing is triggered, you must make sure that you do not start it again the next second. If you do it after successful completion, and the task is somehow asynchronous, that might be too late and it gets processed twice....

Comment: ... but if you do set the event to "done" immediately after the call, and the server crashes during the real processing, it never gets completely processed. Of course that can be mitigated but it becomes complicated quickly and will always be a potential source of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely prefer Method 2.

Method 1 is necessarily a compromise between precision (regarding the exact time of execution) and wasted CPU cycles. The only excuse to use Method 1 would be when the execution of some events has an influence on the desired start time of other events.